# How to open some location in new tab in existing nautilus window? (from console)

Tags: linux, gnome, console, nautilus

I want to type something in console that will open some location (on example home dir) in already opened nautilus window. Is it possible?

Comment: what's so bad about spawning a new nautilus window with the `nautilus` command?

Comment: Very often I have 20+ windows and many tabs within. It is simpler for me to browse through tabs, then looking for right window. And at least for me it would be much simpler (based on my experience with browsers, shells etc.)

Comment: Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: progress some years later, details here -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/55656/open-nautilus-as-new-tab-in-existing-window

Comment: it is a bit tricky but now is possible with [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secNautilusRestartAndRestoreTabs.sh)

Answer (score 3):

No, I'm afraid you're asking for the impossbile.

You'd need dbus or something for that. Or an in-built management in Nautilus. Sadly as far as I know there is nothing like that available. (It won't separate it like n1t3 (Nautilus1 window, tab 3)).

Comment: I know that Nautilus doesn't have such option build in. That's why I'm asking a question on "super user" :). When I click "open location in new tab" nautilus sends something somewhere. If I can send that something with a script (that is what I meant by "type something in a console) or simple program, I would then manage to add functionality that I find missing. So any direction in this topic can be useful for me.

Comment: That's what I meant on managing. Well. I'll check the source code tomorrow and will report.

Comment: Did you find something?

Comment: Nah, nothing. Maybe you should check #gnome on IRC as a last resort. Sadly there are no people usually on that room, that's why I parted from Gnome. (Okay just one of the soo many reason.)

Comment: there is now, you are right [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secNautilusRestartAndRestoreTabs.sh) uses qdbus!

Comment: Yeah @aquarius. Comment on OP's question so he gets a notification as well. Sad thing about SU that the majority of the answers on the site get just outdated.